# Cannot access hard disks from FreeBSD installation CD

Tags: freebsd, system-installation

I have been using GNU/Linux for several years and now I am giving FreeBSD a try.

Yesterday I managed to install FreeBSD 10.2 on an old computer using a 5 GB partition. I only installed the base system and a few programs and everything seems to work fine. The disk on which I installed FreeBSD contains another primary partition which is used by GNU/Linux.

Today I wanted to try installing FreeBSD on a 43 GB spare disk on another computer. The disk has three primary (empty) partitions already. Using `fdisk` under GNU/Linux I set the type of one partition to `a5` (FreeBSD): I wanted to install FreeBSD on this partition / slice. I then booted the FreeBSD installation CD and expected I would only need to create labels inside the FreeBSD slice, but the FreeBSD `fdisk` that is started by the installer won't see any partition at all! It reports the whole disk as unused and offers to create a new slice.

For me it is OK to use the whole disk, but why doesn't `fdisk` see the existing slices? Note that on the older computer I was able to see and use a 5 GB partition using the same installation CD.

Am I overlooking something?

**EDIT**

I found out there are problems when trying to access the two disks from FreeBSD. After booting the installation CD I opened a shell. I looked for my two disks. If I understood correctly, they are

```
/dev/ad0           # Blank 43 GB disk where I want to install FreeBSD
/dev/ad2           # 60 GB disk with working Debian 8 on it
```

When I try to access **both** disks from the shell with

```
# diskinfo -c ad0
# diskinfo -c ad2
```

I get error messages:

```
(ada1:ata1:0:0:0) READ_DMA. ACB: c8 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 01 00
(ada1:ata1:0:0:0) CAM status: ATA Status Error
(ada1:ata1:0:0:0) ATA status: 51 (DRDY SERV ERR), error: 84 (ICRC ABRT )
(ada1:ata1:0:0:0) RES: 51 84 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
(ada1:ata1:0:0:0) Error 5, Retries exhausted
diskinfo: read: Input/output error
```

Note that I get the same error on both disks while I can access both disks from Debian. The only thing I can think of is that I need to change some BIOS setting, but I have no idea what the problem could be.

**EDIT 2**

Booting with

```
hw.ata.ata_dma=0
```

seems to solve the problem. I got the hint from [here](http://freebsd.1045724.n5.nabble.com/gmirror-slice-insertion-quot-FAILURE-READ-DMA-status-51-lt-READY-DSC-ERROR-gt-quot-td3814036.html). Still, I am not sure what the problem is and why setting this variable would solve it.
IMO the problem should not be caused by a bad drive because at least one of the disks has no errors (checked it recently for bad blocks). I will check the other disk now.

Answer (score 0):

The "geom disk list" command will show you which disk is which.  The problem in dmesg looks like a disk problem, but if the hw.ata.ata_dma=0 workaround worked, then it's probably something between the driver and the controller.